# Missing distribution spec error using pip install from requirements

Tags: django, virtualenv, pip

I have just created a fresh virtualenv into which I want to run my `pip install`. However, I'm getting this error:

```
raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '/path/to/dir/requirements.txt')
```

My **requirements.txt**:

```
Django==1.3
Jinja2==2.6
MySQL-python==1.2.3
PIL==1.1.7
Pygments==1.5
Sphinx==1.1.3
Werkzeug==0.8.3
django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4
django-excel-response==1.0
django-extensions==0.8
docutils==0.9.1
ipython==0.12
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must be doing something wrong. Something like: `pip install path/to/requirements.txt`, but the requirements file must be passed with `-r` argument:

`pip install -r path/to/requirements.txt`

Hugs.

Comment: ha! I forgot the `-r` flag. And not the first time... It would still be nice to have an error message which points that out though. Thanks.

Comment: I had a ~ at the bottom of mine.  Trying to find that error using vi was not easy :-).

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to complete the answer if anyone runs in the same variant as I did: I was running everything on a Windows environment (windows 7). Under powershell, I had ran

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

When I tested on a new virtualenv, I had the same error as above. The problem was an encoding issue (ugh): make sure the requirements.txt file is written in UTF-8 (without BOM). Notepad++ or sublime text can make sure of that.

Hope it helps anyone else for the which the answer above was not enough.

Comment: Thanks - looks like powershell saves requirements.txt as unicode

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, which on the face of it, looked exactly like the OP's.

Answer (score 2):

My issue ending up being that in some terminals, – and - look exactly the same.  I had –r and it threw this error.  You want -r.

Answer (score 0):

if you are pushing to Azure, even with utf-8 you might also run into this problem:

ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '\xef\xbb\xbfDjango==1.11.4')

the safe way is to save as requirements.txt as ansi file.

well, given you are running on windows